# how to update selectbox data in angular js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

Hi whats all I want is to select a value from selectbox in angularjs and that value gets updated in  the database I am getting my data in json array
from php function and mysql databse: Keeping in view that the updated value would be shown as default value in selectbox
NOTE:you have to target only select box

```html
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="user in $data | filter:searchText">
               
               <td data-title="'pkCategoryId'" >{{$index + 1}}</td>
               <td data-title="'Name'" >{{user.Name}}</td>
              <!--  <td data-title="'Order'">{{user.Order}}</td> -->
                <td> <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="rec.orders"  name="Order">
      <option ng-repeat="orders in order" 
      ng-selected="{{orders.Order == user.Order}}"  value="{{orders.order}}">{{orders.Order}}      </option>
                                  </select> </td>
               <td data-title="'Status'">{{user.Status}}</td>   
               <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-info"  title="SEO" ui-sref="app.seomanage_category({id:user.pkCategoryId})">  
                    <em class="fa fa-search"></em>
                </button> </td>           
              
            </tr>
         
      </table>
```

here is my js

```js
 $scope.updateValue(rec){

  $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
   //url: 'api/manage_features/update/'+id, //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url 
   url: 'api/AdminArea/category/updateValue/'+id,
   method: 'POST', 
   headers: {'header-key': '83c238df1650bccb2d1aa4495723c63f07672ee8'}, 
   withCredentials: true, 
   data:rec , //{data:rec},
   //data: {name:$scope.name,price:$scope.price},
    }).progress(function(evt) {
   console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      toaster.pop('success', 'Order', 'Order Updated successfully.');
        setTimeout(function(){ $state.go('app.manage_category'); }, 3000);
      $scope.$root.$broadcast("myDocEventReload", {});
    })
 
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting updated value in response from server?

Comment: which directive should i use ngchange? or something else because i m confused with that

Comment: Just tell me what is your response from server. Are you getting the value which you wnat to update in select box.